# Automatically Show Maintenance Page when there is a script error

Tags: html, asp.net, runtime-error

The agency I work for have a client who keeps experiencing errors on his website. For example, randomly throughout the day, the website will encounter a number of different runtime errors, normally to do with the mail handler.

Now, the client is having the system rebuilt in a different platform, but in the meantime we want an automatic maintenance page to flag up whenever the website goes down.

At present, the error code reads something like this:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute() in path\to\_Layout.cshtml:18
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +198
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +104
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +90
   System.Web.WebPages.<>c__DisplayClass7.<RenderPageCore>b__6(TextWriter writer) +230
   System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer) +10
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) +80
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body) +64
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() +262
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +98
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +257
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +291
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17() +23
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +245
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +22
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +176
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +75
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +99
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9658236
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

What we want is an automatic, HTML-based error page to appear and disappear depending upon whether or not there is an error.

The way I have it envisioned is that the new index page would first query the website's main page, and if there is no error display it, or disable the maintenance mode page if an error is present.

I hope that makes sense.

Is it possible to achieve this within the ASP.NET framework?

The website is currently using v2.0.50727.

Appreciate any help you guys can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following line to the system.web node in the web.config file:

`<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/errorPage.html" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"></customErrors>`

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is redirect the user to your custom error page whenever any type of unhandled exception occurs in your application, you can use Global.asax to redirect the user like this:

```
protected void Application_Error()
{
    Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
    Response.Clear();

    // clear error on server
    Server.ClearError();

    var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
    if (httpContext != null)
        httpContext.Response.Redirect("~/MyCustomErorPage.html");
}
```

Ideally you should be handling the exception where it occurs by implementing HandleErrorAttribute.OnException or Controller.OnException, logging the excepton, and redirecting the user from there.

If you want a quick and dirty solution (as it seems you already know the cause of the exception), the Global.asax solution should achieve what you're asking.